# Поиск подграфов , гомеоморфных К3,3 и К5 Java

Tags: java, графы

*Теорема Понтрягина - Куратовского.*
 Граф планарен тогда и только тогда, когда он не содержит подграфов, гомеоморфных К5 или К3,3

Гомеоморфность в данном контексте обозначает отношение эквивалентности.

Задание стоит в следующем , реализовать программу , которая будет проверять граф на планарность ссылаясь на эту теорему (не Гамма - алгоритм) . Вопрос в следующем : существует - ли алгоритм перебора подграфов в графе и как их проверять на гомеомерфность с К5 и К3,3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public Vertex[] getCycleLen5() {

    Vertex[] adjList = graph.getAdjList();
    boolean[][] aMatrix = createAdjMatrix(adjList);

    //Const for max len of cycles;
    final int n = 5;
    Vertex[]subGraph = new Vertex[n];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        subGraph[i] = new Vertex();

    for (int a = 0 ; a < graph.getVertices() ; a++)
        for (int b = a + 1 ; b < graph.getVertices() ; b++) {
            if (!aMatrix[a][b]) continue;
            for (int c = b + 1; c < graph.getVertices() ; c++) {
                if (!aMatrix[b][c]) continue;
                for (int d = c + 1; d < graph.getVertices() ; d++) {
                    if (!aMatrix[c][d]) continue;
                    for (int e = d + 1; e < graph.getVertices() ; e++)
                        if (aMatrix[d][e] && aMatrix[e][a]) {
                             subGraph[0] = adjList[a];
                             subGraph[1] = adjList[b];
                             subGraph[2] = adjList[c];
                             subGraph[3] = adjList[d];
                             subGraph[4] = adjList[e];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return subGraph;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте искать циклы длины 5 и 6 и проверять их ребра не входящие в цикл. А для поиска циклов алгоритм нагуглить, да и придумать, не сложно.

Comment: @rdorn поиск циклов - поиск в глубину , а вот "проверять их ребра , невходящие в цикл" немного не понял , пожалуйста , объясните

Comment: @rdorn "проверяем , что ребра вершин не входящие в цикл не образуют граф К5" , собственно в этом и есть мой вопрос :)

Comment: @rdorn можете привести псевдокод ?

Comment: немного  позже, сейчас бежать надо, могу на шарпе написать. он не сильно отличается, думаю  перевести сможете без проблем

Comment: @rdorn было бы замечательно :)

Comment: Удалил лишние комментарии, постарался не использовать конструкции специфичные только для шарпа

Comment: **ВНИМАНИЕ студентота: предложенный тут ответ ошибочен, так как ищет подграфы, изоморфные К3,3 и К5, а не гомеоморфные оным.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ок, раз поиск циклов в графе проблем не вызывает и устраивает ответ на C# (см. комментарии к вопросу), то приведу простое решение в лоб. LiNQ не используется для упрощения переноса в Java, хотя с ним было бы компактнее.

Определим простой класс вершины не ориентированного графа (необходимый минимум):

```
class Vertex
{
    public List<Vertex> Adges = new List<Vertex>();
    public bool HasAdgeToVertex(Vertex vertex)
    {
        foreach(var adge in Adges)
        {
            if (adge == vertex) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Теперь нужны две функции проверки на то, что вершины найденного цикла являются графом K5 или K3,3

Проверка на K5:

```
bool IsK5graph(Vertex[] subgraph)
{
    bool result = false;
    int n = 5;
    if (subgraph.Length == n)
    {
        result = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                result &= subgraph[i].HasAdgeToVertex(subgraph[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Просто проверяем что для данного набора вершин есть все 10 необходимых ребер.

Аналогично для K3,3, но с учетом его особенностей, немного изменим внутренний цикл проверки:

```
bool IsK33graph(Vertex[] subgraph)
{
    bool result = false;
    int n = 6;
    if (subgraph.Length == n)
    {
        result = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j += 2)
            {
                result &= subgraph[i].HasAdgeToVertex(subgraph[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Обе проверки отрабатывают за N итераций, где N - число ребер графа K5 и K3,3 соответственно. Учитывая малые N, оптимизация проверки путем уменьшения количества итераций и усложнения кода проверки может не дать никакого или даже отрицательный эффект на общее время проверки графа. Но можно оптимизировать проверку наличия ребра у вершины, например заменой List для хранения смежных вершин, на HashSet если исходный граф не содержит параллельных ребер.

---

Если задавать ребра через матрицу смежности, то матрица для К5, будет выглядеть так, для неориентированного графа:

```
    1 2 3 4 5
    ---------
1 | 0 1 1 1 1 |
2 | 1 0 1 1 1 |
3 | 1 1 0 1 1 |
4 | 1 1 1 0 1 |
5 | 1 1 1 1 0 |
```

Тогда решение можно свести к построению матрицы смежности для вершин найденного цикла и проверки, что она не совпадает с заданной. С целью ускорения процесса, можно объединить построение и проверку матриц смежности на совпадение. Если основной граф задан через матрицу смежности, то такой вариант может оказаться удобным.

Для К3,3 матрица такая:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6
    -----------
1 | 0 1 0 1 0 1 |
2 | 1 0 1 0 1 0 |
3 | 0 1 0 1 0 1 |
4 | 1 0 1 0 1 0 |
5 | 0 1 0 1 0 1 |
6 | 1 0 1 0 1 0 |
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за подробное разъяснение и код , очень пригодится.

Comment: @K.Zakhar пользуйтесь, а спасибо тут галочкой говорят обычно или отметкой "ответ полезен" рядом с рейтингом. Галочку "ответ" можно переставить если кто-то напишет более подходящий ответ =)

Comment: Только вот судя по вашему коду , нужно искать не циклы длинной 5 , а подграфы на пяти вершинах. Более формально : циклы представляют собой "контур" на графе

Comment: эм... а контур не образует подграф? это что-то новое

Comment: если мы нашли вершины контура, а мы их в любом случае находим, т.к. по ним идем для определения контура, то дальше остается проверить что вершины контура не образуют по совместительству и неудобный нам подграф

Comment: ну я написал на формальном языке , а так - конечно образует , но алгоритм поиска немного усложняется. Для графа К5 на рисунке цикл [1,2,3,4,5] и ваш алгоритм проверки на гомеоморфность с К5 для него будет выдавать false

Comment: @K.Zakhar а как вы вершины цикла передаете? уж не с задвоеной ли первой вешиной

Comment: найденные циклы представляют собой ArrayList<Integer>[] Cycle . Для данного примера Cycle[0] = [0,1,2,3,4] , если Вы про это

Comment: @K.Zakhar а ребра как указываете, если у вас вершина это просто число? Скорее всего где то там ошибка, у меня сделано с расчетом на то, что вершина это объект и знает о своих ребрах

Comment: да , спасибо , но вот тогда возникает вопрос , как находить и представлять эти циклы ))
Код , как это сделал я , оставлю в вопросе.

Comment: @K.Zakhar можно и через матрицы смежности, только строить их нужно аккуратно.

Comment: ну , так как у нас ограничение на количнство вершин (не более 20) , я принял решение хранить их в матрице смежности. Думаю , что это не сильно будет кушать память :).

Comment: аккуратно в каком плане ?

Comment: @K.Zakhar аккуратно в плане внимательно =) очень легко сделать ошибку просто случайно. С моделью на базе объектов, все это можно переложить на плечи самих объектов.

Comment: как построить матрицу найденного цикла я так и не придумал , но разве Ваш алгоритм будет работать если будет найден цикл на вершинах [7 , 33 , 45 , 67 , 88] , нужно еще как -то переоценить вершины . Если считать их mod 5 , то тогда возникает ситуация [2 , 3, 0 , 2 , 3] , что очень проблемно обрабатывать :C

Comment: Похоже здесь нету других путей кроме как строить матрицу найденного цикла , но пока я так и не придумал , как это реализовать :(

Comment: @K.Zakhar к сожалению, похоже что проблема не в алгоритме, а в понимании как строить матрицы смежности и сними работать дальше. Оформите отдельным вопросом с метками Алгоритм, без указания языка. Или попробуйте все таки использовать предложенный вариант с явным созданием класса для описания вершин графа. Касательно вашего последнего вопроса - не нужно переоценивать вершины, у вас есть индексы массива вершин, а какие именно в нем вершины не имеет значения для алгоритма